# HTML Meta Viewport only for smartphones

Tags: html, css, media-queries, meta-tags

I'm building my first responsive page and have problems with "Meta Viewport".

I'm using this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes" />
```

On Desktop and iPhone, I see the result I wanted. But my iPad the result is . I just want to use `meta name="viewport"` for smartphones. Is there a way to restrict this tag for just smartphones?

EDIT:
I want just one breakpoint for smartphones. The problem is, when i add the "Meta Viewport" tag to head, than i have a problem. I want that this meta tag only appears, when max-width==480px.

**EDIT 2 -> MY SOLUTION:**

"screen.width" is returning the same value as window.innerWidth after adding "Meta Viewport: device-width". Its now working on desktop, ipad and iPhone5.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( screen.width < 480 ) {
    document.write( '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />' );
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 280px) and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="files/css/smartphones.css" />
```

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" ...>` will only affect mobile devices

Comment: the problem is my ipad. tablets should ignore the tag

Comment: You're not too detailed, but are you sure you cannot solve your issue by adjusting the @media queries instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get iOS (iPhone or iPad) to ignore the viewport tag. What you can do is browser-sniff for iPad and dynamically remove the viewport tag with javascript. OR, add the viewport tag only if the user-agent is a phone and not a tablet.

Something like this:

```
if (navigator.platform === 'iPad') {
    var viewport = document.getElementsByName("viewport")[0]
    viewport.parentNode.removeChild(viewport)
}
```

Comment: yes but the problem is not just ipad. the main problem in your sample is to detect android tablets to exclude them too.

Comment: Exactly. The problem with browser-sniffing is that collecting the gigantic list of "all tablets" to test against is very difficult and hard to maintain. There are now tablets that are smaller than phones, and phones that are larger than tablets. The only one who knows which devices you want to exclude is you. I would advise not testing for tablets, and instead, make your breakpoints cover all scenarios. If you must browser-sniff, there are plenty of open source plugins to help you.